# Clojure map nesting

Tags: clojure

I have a vector structure like this...

```
[{:email "email@gmail.com", :password "pass"} 
 {:email "email2@yahoo.com", :password "pass2"} 
 {:email "email3@yahoo.com", :password "pass3"} 
 {:email "email4@gmail.com", :password "pass4"}]
```

How can i make a map out of this that will look like this?The two email values must be same...

```
 {{"email@gmail.com"{:email "email@gmail.com", :password "pass"}}, 
  {"email2@yahoo.com"{:email "email2@yahoo.com", :password "pass2"}}, 
  {"email3@yahoo.com" {:email "email3@yahoo.com", :password "pass3"}} ,
  {"email4@gmail.com"{:email "email4@gmail.com", :password "pass4"}}
```

I am a bit new to clojure,so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(def a [{:email "email@gmail.com", :password "pass"}
        {:email "email2@yahoo.com", :password "pass2"}
        {:email "email3@yahoo.com", :password "pass3"}
        {:email "email4@gmail.com", :password "pass4"}])

(zipmap (map :email a) a)
```

Creates a sequence of the email addresses and then zips that and the vector of the original maps into a new map with the addresses as the keys and the original maps as the values.

(think of the list of emails presented vertically on the left and the original map entries presented vertically on the right and a zip moving down joining them together)

Comment: how can i add a function to all values in :password keyword?I am trying to incorporate (creds/hash-bcrypt "string/value of password") function.

Comment: If you're asking how to transform the value associated with :password then assoc will "overwrite" if the key already exists. e.g. (zipmap (map :email a) (map #(assoc % :password (keyword (:password %))) a)) to transform the string to a keyword

Comment: no,i want to implement my function on all values in :password keyword.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at. Perhaps ask as another question with some examples of the output you want?

Comment: i already did that,i got that question answered...now i am problem free.:D thanks once again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (though your output will be nested in a vector) is to use [`group-by`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/group-by):

```
user=> (def a [{:email "email@gmail.com", :password "pass"}
        {:email "email2@yahoo.com", :password "pass2"}
        {:email "email3@yahoo.com", :password "pass3"}
        {:email "email4@gmail.com", :password "pass4"}])
#'user/a
user=> (group-by :email a)
{"email@gmail.com" [{:email "email@gmail.com", :password "pass"}], "email2@yahoo.com" [{:email "email2@yahoo.com", :password "pass2"}], "email3@yahoo.com" [{:email "email3@yahoo.com", :password "pass3"}], "email4@gmail.com" [{:email "email4@gmail.com", :password "pass4"}]}
user=>
```

Comment: neat solution,but i needed it to be map...status203 answered my question,but thank you anyways.

Comment: really easy to fix though `(map (fn [[k [v]]] {k v}) (group-by :email a))`